# Finding the root of a function in Python with function in function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a function with scalar values, say  `myFunction`, which depends on several parameters, say `x` and `y`. `x` is a scalar, and `y` could be a list for example (although I have more parameters of various types in my application).

For every fixed value of `y`, `myFunction` has a unique root in `x`, which I would like to compute (as a function of `y`).

The way I am doing it is as follows:

```
from scipy import optimize

def myFunction(x,y):
    return ...


def myRoot(y):
    def localFunction(x):
        return myFunction(x,y)
    return optimize.root_scalar(localFunction,x0=0).root
```

It turns out, since I have to run this thousands of times, that this is too slow for my purpose. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to the problem of finding the root. Have you taken a look at general performance optimisation strategies, such as ``multiprocessing``?

Comment: You can consider running it using multi processing. Pre conditions: 1) It makes sense for your code to run in parallel 2) you have multi core machine. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: So there is no better way of doing it in terms of implementation?

Comment: You are hiding what is in myFunction. Also you probably should tag your question with scipy

Comment: What is slow about it? Is it the fact that myFunction takes a long time to return? If that is the case, then fundamentally it is going to be slow to find several thousand roots of it. If scipy is doing a lot of function calls to find each root, then maybe you can tweak the options of scipy.root_scalar to reduce that (e.g. using a different method, specifying bounds if possible, reducing tolerance for the solver)